# Does it matter what channel a Wi-Fi router uses?

Tags: wireless-networking, signal-strength

Not considering interference by other devices, does it matter whether you set your Wi-Fi router to a lower or higher channel of the 2.4 GHz band? Is the range the same?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the power allowed on any of the 2.4GHz channels is the same, so the range is the same. However, some regulatory agencies have strict rules about out-of-band emissions on the edge of the band, and if a manufacturer was having a problem getting their radio to pass the out-of-band emissions test at one edge of the band or the other, they may have chosen to work around the problem by decreasing their transmit power on band-edge channels (1 and 11, or 1 and 13) to get below the failure threshold.

So, without actually carefully measuring the power output of your box using radio laboratory equipment, it's hard to say, but channel 6 might be a better choice on some boxes rather than a band-edge channel.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2.4 gig band it doesn't make a different (assuming that all the gear can see the channel - different gear has different channels as some countriess have fewer bands).

In the 5 gig band, [the higher frequencies typically allow for more power](http://www.wisp.net.au/5ghz-channel-spectral-width-australia-pm-16.html), also [this](http://www.solwise.co.uk/wireless-5.htm).